# Embedded Internet Explorer 6 control and HTTP 302

Tags: internet-explorer-6

We have a .NET application using the WebBrowser control. On Windows XP SP3 systems with Internet Explorer 6 the application is not able to login to a web site. The control raises the NavigateError event with error code is 302 and then it displays the "Navigation canceled" page.
We've tried a few workarounds and now we're begging the web site admin to change the login page to use a script instead of sending a HTTP 302 (we can do this because the application needs to be able to access only a specific web site).
However, we would like to have a normal solution to this problem.
Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Goodness, explorer 6 *still* hasn't died?

I had a similar problem with redirects on explorer 6 a few years ago, and the problem went away when I *removed* the encoding meta tag in the head part of the html.  Go figure.

In other words, it's very likely due to something totally unrelated to the redirect.  That's ie6.